# How much it cost to deploy a smart contract which creates more smart contracts on Ethereum MainNet?

Tags: contract-deployment, gas-price, deployed-bytecode

I want to create a smart contract which deploy smart contract to each user who use it "AllUserMetaData", therefore for each user one smart contract will be deploy.

How much does it cost to deploy "AllUserMetaData" contract?

Comment: Can you share a link to AllUserMetaData contract?

Comment: I want, but I haven't it yet, because I want to create a dapp, so before to start I need to make sure which the application based on smart contract will be profitable, but I realize it   isn't.

Answer (score 1):

try it in a testnet, see how much gas it cost and then use the gas price of the mainnet, it definitely won't be cheap

Comment: Thanks so much! I could expect it